# Rails Search [params] error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, model

Hi I have a search bar for my Firms.. however it seems to be throwing up and error and I cannot work out why!

My View

application.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag firms_path, :method => 'get', :class => 'form-search'  do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => 'input-medium search-query', :placeholder => 'Firm name' %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil ,:class => 'btn' %>
<% end %>
```

My firms_controller.rb

```
def index
 @firms = Firm.search(params[:search])
end


def self.search(search)
  if search
   where(['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"]).page(params[:id])
  else
   scoped
  end
end
```

This used to work fine, but now it is tossing up this error.

```
NameError in FirmsController#index

undefined local variable or method `params' for #<Class:0x007f93cd8b2ac8>

app/models/firm.rb:13:in `search'
app/controllers/firms_controller.rb:8:in `index'
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance for any help

Ross

Comment: `params` is a controller method so can not be used from a method inside one of your models.

Comment: In which table you are finding name like....

Comment: I am calling the self.search method on the Firm table, with Firm.search, and I thought that the [params]:search in the view, tied it to the argument of the controller .search method?

Comment: In your controller, `params` is a method call that (slight simplification) returns a hash. `params[:search]` therefore gives the value of the search parameter from that hash as a String. This string is then passed to your `Firm.search`. By the time you're in `Firm.search` there is no longer anything tying you back to the controller. [Mike's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10140966/63034) is one possible solution that works. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify

```
def index
 @firms = Firm.search(params[:search], params[:id])
end

def self.search(search, id)
 if search
   where(['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"]).page(id)
 else
  scoped
 end
end
```

Comment: that works like a dream! thank you mike and thanks @mikej for helping me understand how it works!